# Python: Why does 0.01.as_integer_ratio() return 5764607523034235/576460752303423488

Tags: python, integer, radix

I was working on [question 33 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=33) in Python when I noticed something I do not understand.

The answer to the question needed the denominator given in its lowest common terms. So I thought I would use the `float.as_integer_ratio()` to check what the denominator was. It turns out that `0.01.as_integer_ratio()` returns `(5764607523034235, 576460752303423488)` and `0.1.as_integer_ratio()` returns `(3602879701896397, 36028797018963968)` instead of the expected `1/100` and `1/10`.

Why does it behave like this? I am guessing it has something to do with how these numbers are stored on the computer. I have also tried the Fractions library from Python but this gives the same results. I hope someone can explain why it behaves like this to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A computer cannot usually calculate with decimal numbers to the base 10. I am not sure if it is different for a quantum computer, but normally numbers are calculated internally to base 2.

Without that knowledge, this can be a shocking moment:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 0.3
False
```

That means that normally an approximation is used to get a good representation of that numbers. Because of these approximations, `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1` is not `0.3`.

So a simple `0.1` (base 10) becomes `0.0001 1001 1001 1001...` (base 2, endless). But fractions for the rescue and to get rid of the approximations! `float.as_integer_ratio()` wants to be exact:

> Return a pair of integers whose **ratio is exactly equal** to the original float and with a positive denominator.

(See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio), emphasis mine.)

So the method is using an algorithm to calculate the exact ratio, e.g. from `0.1` and the best numbers the algorithm can found is `3602879701896397` and `36028797018963968`. It seems that the numbers are good, because the fractions library gets the same results (as you said).

BTW: Everything is fine in base 10 if you're calculating on decimal numbers which you can handle also in base 2, e.g. `0.5` (=`0.1` to base 2):

```
>>> 0.5.as_integer_ratio()
(1, 2)
```

If you want to read more, there is also a good site with many detailed information and further links in the [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: "A computer cannot calculate with decimals to base 10." - sure it can, easily. You just didn't tell it to.

Answer (score 4):

As colidyre mentioned, the problem is with the inaccuracies of floating point representation. You can use the [limit_denominator method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) in the fractions library to get the correct result.

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction(0.01).limit_denominator(100000)
1/100
```